Collect StateFlow in multiple views
I have a StateFlow that I'd like to be collected in 2 different views: An Activity and a Fragment. I need to update UI in the Activity and Fragment via the same flow.
Using the default asStateFlow() or asSharedFlow() dont work. I read about stateIn and shareIn which seem to have the functionality to solve this exact problem. I tried both but they did not work. Here's an example of stateIn. I also tried shareIn and the results were same. I also tried SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed() but again, the results were same. What am I doing wrong?
States:
sealed class SearchStates {
    class ConfigLoaded(val searchConfigList: List<String>): SearchStates()
    class Loading(val query: String): SearchStates()
}

Base ViewModel:
// This ViewModel is extended by ActivityViewModel and FragmentViewModel
// hence the Activity and Fragment can access this flow
@HiltViewModel
open class BaseSearchViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private val _state: MutableStateFlow<SearchStates> = MutableStateFlow(SearchStates.Started)
    val state = _state.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, SearchStates.Started)
//  ShareIn usage
//  val state = _state.shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed())

    fun onConfigLoadedd(configList: List<String>) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.value = SearchStates.ConfigLoaded(configList)
        }
    }

    fun onLoading(query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.value = SearchStates.Loading(query)
        }
    }
}

Activity ViewModel extending the BaseSearchViewModel:
@HiltViewModel
class SearchActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(

) : BaseSearchViewModel() {

    fun onCreate() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            listOf("1","2","3").let {
                onConfigLoaded(it)
            }
        }
    }
    
    fun updateSearchQuery(query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // Activity updates the state to Loading via BaseSearchViewModel
            // I want to receive this new state in Activity and Fragment
            onLoading(query)
    }
}

Fragment ViewModel extending the BaseSearchViewModel:
@HiltViewModel
class SearchFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(

) : BaseSearchViewModel() {
    
}

Activity:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: SearchActivityViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySearchBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySearchBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        bindViewActions()
        observeViewModel()
        viewModel.onCreate()
    }

    private fun bindViewActions() {
        activityButton.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.updateSearchQuery("sleep")
        }
    }        
    
    private fun observeViewModel() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
                viewModel.state.collect {
                    when (it) {
                        is SearchStates.ConfigLoaded -> {
                            addFragments(it)
                        }

                        is SearchStates.Loading -> {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Activity Loading: ${it.query}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun addFragments(configs: List<String>) {
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        configs.forEach { config ->
            val fragment = SearchFragment()
            fragmentsList.add(fragment)
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.searchFragmentContainer, fragment)
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }
}

Fragment:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SearchFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: SearchFragmentViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSearchBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = FragmentSearchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        observeViewModel()
    }
    
    private fun observeViewModel() {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch { 
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
                viewModel.state.collect {
                    when (it) {
                        is SearchStates.Loading -> {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Fragment Loading: ${it.query}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

activity_search.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activityButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/searchFragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </LinearLayout>

</layout>

fragment_search.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

   </LinearLayout>

</layout>

Logcat output:
2024-07-12 18:07:40.955  D  Activity Loading: sleep

Expected Logcat output:
2024-07-12 18:07:40.955  D  Activity Loading: sleep
2024-07-12 18:07:40.955  D  Fragment Loading: sleep


There were several bugs in your view model code that prevented it from compiling. I fixed it, please verify that it is still what you intend.

I also updated the log output to be "Activity Loading: sleep" instead of "SearchActivity Loading: sleep". The latter cannot be produced with the code you provided.

@Leviathan Yes looks fine. Thanks.

Your view model seems ok (although you should use the much easier asStateFlow), but you omitted the most important part: How are your view model instances created? In the code comments you talk about your Activity and Fragment using view models that are derived from BaseSearchViewModel. So they actually will always have separate instances. And separate instances obviously don't share their state so this can never work as expected. But even when you would directly use BaseSearchViewModel you need to make sure you use the same instance in both cases. Please add the relevant code.

@Leviathan I've updated the code. I think you nailed it. Rookie mistake from my part, but what would be a good way to achieve the result? Is there a good way to have the same instance of BaseSearchViewModel in Activity and Fragment? Is that a good approach? Or should I just use separate states for Activity and Fragment? Using separate states will lead to some duplication in other states like onError and onNoResults and I'm trying to avoid that.

You still didn't show us how you construct the view model instances. @Inject looks like dependency injection, but neither did you explain what framework you use nor how you actually tell the DI framework to provide an instance or how you obtain one for your views. On Stack Overflow you always need to provide reproducible code in your question, as it is described here: [mre]

@Leviathan I've added all necessary code which shows how viewModels are created, how fragments are added to activity, how activity updates the Loading state. You should be able to reproduce the setup on your side. Thanks for your patience.
